# Sql Date Grouping with avaliable dates in database

Tags: sql-server

```
ID         dateandtime  EmailID
73  6/8/2014 00:00:00   2
74  6/9/2014 00:00:00   2
75  6/10/2014 00:00:00  2
76  6/11/2014 00:00:00  2
77  6/12/2014 00:00:00  2
78  6/13/2014 00:00:00  2
79  6/14/2014 00:00:00  2
80  6/16/2014 00:00:00  2
81  6/17/2014 00:00:00  4
82  6/18/2014 00:00:00  4
83  6/19/2014 00:00:00  4
84  6/20/2014 00:00:00  4
89  6/27/2014 00:00:00  4
90  6/28/2014 00:00:00  4
91  6/29/2014 00:00:00  4
92  6/30/2014 00:00:00  4
93  6/1/2014 00:00:00   4
94  6/2/2014 00:00:00   4
95  6/3/2014 00:00:00   2
96  6/4/2014 00:00:00   2
97  6/5/2014 00:00:00   2
98  6/6/2014 00:00:00   2
99  6/7/2014 00:00:00   2
100 6/21/2014 00:00:00  4
101 6/22/2014 00:00:00  4
102 6/23/2014 00:00:00  4
103 6/24/2014 00:00:00  4
104 7/1/2014 00:00:00   4
105 7/2/2014 00:00:00   4
106 7/3/2014 00:00:00   4
121 7/6/2014 00:00:00   2
122 7/7/2014 00:00:00   2
123 7/8/2014 00:00:00   2
```

above record through i can generate below group of all date like as

```
StartDate - EndDate    EmailID
6/1/2014 -  6/2/2014     4
6/3/2014 -  6/14/2014    2
6/16/2014 - 6/16/2014    2
6/17/2014 - 6/24/2014    4
6/27/2014 - 6/30/2014    4 
7/1/2014  - 7/3/2014     4
```

i trying to find, for each EmailID, the contiguous blocks of dates?
any one solve this question
thanks in advance

Comment: This is a good question.  There are two ways you can improve it.  The first is to give the columns reasonable names.  Your sample data has four columns but only two names.  Second, you can set up a SQL Fiddle (www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: hello i can improve my question can you solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick for you. First identify the range starts and then the range ends and at the same time set a range identity. Last merge the range start and end sets.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    [ID] INT,
    [Date] DATE,
    [EmailID] INT
)
INSERT INTO
    @Data
VALUES
    (  73, '2014-06-08', 2 ),
    (  74, '2014-06-09', 2 ),
    (  75, '2014-06-10', 2 ),
    (  76, '2014-06-11', 2 ),
    (  77, '2014-06-12', 2 ),
    (  78, '2014-06-13', 2 ),
    (  79, '2014-06-14', 2 ),
    (  80, '2014-06-16', 2 ),
    (  81, '2014-06-17', 4 ),
    (  82, '2014-06-18', 4 ),
    (  83, '2014-06-19', 4 ),
    (  84, '2014-06-20', 4 ),
    (  89, '2014-06-27', 4 ),
    (  90, '2014-06-28', 4 ),
    (  91, '2014-06-29', 4 ),
    (  92, '2014-06-30', 4 ),
    (  93, '2014-06-01', 4 ),
    (  94, '2014-06-02', 4 ),
    (  95, '2014-06-03', 2 ),
    (  96, '2014-06-04', 2 ),
    (  97, '2014-06-05', 2 ),
    (  98, '2014-06-06', 2 ),
    (  99, '2014-06-07', 2 ),
    ( 100, '2014-06-21', 4 ),
    ( 101, '2014-06-22', 4 ),
    ( 102, '2014-06-23', 4 ),
    ( 103, '2014-06-24', 4 ),
    ( 104, '2014-07-01', 4 ),
    ( 105, '2014-07-02', 4 ),
    ( 106, '2014-07-03', 4 ),
    ( 121, '2014-07-06', 2 ),
    ( 122, '2014-07-07', 2 ),
    ( 123, '2014-07-08', 2 );

WITH RangeStart AS (
    SELECT
        l.[Date] AS Start,
        l.EmailID AS EmailId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.[Date]) AS [RangeId]
    FROM
        @Data as l
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Data as r on r.[Date] = DATEADD(day, -1, l.[Date])
            AND r.EmailID = l.EmailID
    WHERE
        r.[Date] IS NULL
), RangeEnd AS (
    SELECT
        l.[Date] AS [End],
        l.EmailID AS EmailId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY l.[Date]) AS [RangeId]
    FROM
        @Data as l
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Data as r on r.[Date] = DATEADD(day, +1, l.[Date])
            AND r.EmailID = l.EmailID
    WHERE
        r.[Date] IS NULL
)
SELECT
    RangeStart.Start,
    RangeEnd.[End],
    RangeStart.EmailId
FROM
    RangeStart
    JOIN RangeEnd ON RangeEnd.RangeId = RangeStart.RangeId
```

The result is not as you might expect, however from what I can se correct.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you question you can use the following code:

`select 
min([Start date - End date]) as StartDate,
max([Start date - End date]) as EndSare,
EmailID
from dbo.T
group by EmaiIID`

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of identifying groups of things that occur in order.  In this case, the groups are in order by date and you want consecutive dates.

You can find the group by using the different in two sequential values.  Enumerate the values by date.  Then enumerate the values by date and `emailId`.  The difference is a constant for sequential values with the same `emailId`.  Here is how it would work in your case:

```
select min(TheDate) as StartDate, max(TheDate) as EndDate, emailId
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day, - row_number() over (order by TheDate), theDate) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by grp, emailId;
```

Comment: your query not working properly because your query generate  6/3/2014 to 6/16/2014 this type of group but i want to generate  6/3/2014 to 6/14/2014 this type.in my data base 6/15/2014 date not avaliable but it can add in two dates group....

Comment: @user2156791 . . . Of course.  The new calculation fixes that.

Comment: hello your query working properly but change two column 06/11/2014 to 06/12/2014 to change emailid to 4 then generate group like this <pre>6/3/2014 00:00:00 6/14/2014 00:00:00 2
6/16/2014 00:00:00 6/16/2014 00:00:00 2
7/6/2014 00:00:00 7/8/2014 00:00:00 2
6/1/2014 00:00:00 6/11/2014 00:00:00 4
6/17/2014 00:00:00 6/24/2014 00:00:00 4
6/27/2014 00:00:00 7/3/2014 00:00:00 4 </pre>type but one error Frist line not proper.this i want to be generated like as 06/03/2014 to 06/09/2014 and Emailid =2 and 06/10/2014 to 06/11/2014 and emailid=4 then next group can u solve this problem and thanks to helps

Comment: @user2156791 . . . You shouldn't ask questions in comments (except for small clarifications on the original).  It sounds like you have a new question, so you should ask another question on Stack Overflow.  (And reference this question in that one.)

Comment: hello i can new question ask for this grouping dates

Comment: Your solution not perfacet for me  but try to find my answer thanks